# Dynamic class creation in C++

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, creation

I've this little program, and I need to create Class object dynamically.
See comments below.

```
#include <conio.h>

#include "student.h"
#include "teacher.h"

int main() {
  short choose;

  do {

    std::cout << "\n1 - Insert student";
    std::cout << "\n2 - Insert teacher";
    std::cout << "\n3 - Show students";
    std::cout << "\n4 - Show teachers";
    std::cout << "\n5 - Exit";
    std::cout << "\n--> ";
    std::cin  >> choose;

    Student *students;

    switch (choose) {
    case 1 :
      // When user choose option 1, I would like to create
      // a new object "Student", so...
      students = new Student();
      // But if user choose 1 another time, how I create
      // another object "Student" ?
      // Could I do something like this?
      //  students = new Student[student_counter];
      break;
    }

  } while (choose != 5);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Student class has a constructor.
Thank you. If something is required just tell me.

Comment: Look into `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `std::vector<Student>`. There's no need for dynamic allocation at all:

```
std::vector<Student> students;

do {
  switch (choose) {
    case 1 :
      students.push_back(Student());
      break;
  }
}while(...)
```

If you **need to** use dynamic allocation, as in it was part of the assignment, just use a `std::vector<Student*>` and `students.push_back(new Student)`. You'll have to manually free the memory afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I understood (I think). And for freeing the memory?

Comment: @user1860848 you'll need to iterate through the vector and call `delete` on every element.

Comment: Or, better yet, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>>`.  I realize you know this, but just for any future visitors...

Comment: Got it. Thank you also to GManNickG & Kerrek SB!

Comment: Ed S. Your solution avoided me a lot of trouble!